# Cannot inject MapStruct mapper into spring-boot JUnit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm trying to write a unit test for a MapStruct mapper with `componentModel="spring"`.

The application works perfectly, including the mapper injection.
The problem is that the mapper is not injected to the test class and I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.onap.sdc.workflow.api.mapping.WorkflowMapperTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'workflowMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.onap.sdc.workflow.services.mappers.WorkflowMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I'm using intellij IDEA and target\generated-sources is marked.

Here is the mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface WorkflowMapper {

@Mapping(source = "properties", target = "category", qualifiedByName = "propertiesToCategoryMapper")
Workflow itemToWorkflow(Item item);

@Mapping(source = "category", target = "properties", qualifiedByName = "categoryToPropertiesMapper")
@InheritInverseConfiguration
Item workflowToItem(Workflow workflow);

@Named("propertiesToCategoryMapper")
default String customPropertiesToCategoryMapper(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    return String.class.cast(properties.get(WorkflowProperty.CATEGORY));
}

@Named("categoryToPropertiesMapper")
default Map<String, Object> customCategoryToPropertiesMapper(String category) {
    return Collections.singletonMap(WorkflowProperty.CATEGORY, category);
}
```

I'm using this mapper in the following code snippet:

```
@Service("workflowManager")
public class WorkflowManagerImpl implements WorkflowManager {

private WorkflowMapper workflowMapper;

@Autowired
public WorkflowManagerImpl(WorkflowMapper workflowMapper) {
    this.workflowMapper = workflowMapper;
}

...some code
```

The unit test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = 
WorkflowMapperTest.WorkflowMapperSpringTestConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class WorkflowMapperTest {

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = WorkflowMapperTest.class)
public static class WorkflowMapperSpringTestConfig { }

@Autowired
WorkflowMapper workflowMapper;

@Test
public void shouldMapItemPropertyToWorkflowCategory() {
    ...some code...
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At a glance, you don't include the bean you wish to test as part of your component scan.

You'd want to update your `@ComponentScan` configuration to include it.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {WorkflowMapperTest.class,
                                     WorkflowMapper.class,
                                     WorkflowMapperImpl.class})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just added WorkflowMapper.class and it did the work. Why should I add the WorkflowMapperImpl.class? do you think I need it too?

Comment: If you are not changing the package of your generated mapper then including only the `WorkflowMapper` is sufficient